# Using .brackets.json for JSLint in Brackets

Tags: json, ide, editor, adobe-brackets

I am trying to get the `.brackets.json` to work with JSLint in Brackets 1.0, as it is described [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences). Actually I want a global JSLint configuration instead of adding the JSLint-lines to each file.

For an MWE, I created [this very simple project](https://github.com/boldt/brackets-test), where I want the JSLint option `plusplus` to be enabled.

As soon I open this project in Brackets, I am still getting an `"Unexpected '++'` JSLint Error. It seems, that the `.brackets.json` is ignored by Brackets.

How can I enable/use the `.brackets.json`?

Comment: Today it is working... weird.

Comment: did you do any changes i am facing same problem

Comment: As far as I know: no.

Comment: I can't get this to work either

Answer (score 0):

In your Brackets editor, go to Debug > Open Preferences File, which will open the brackets.json file. Add this to the file:

`"jslint.options": {
    "plusplus": true
  }`

Save the file, close the Brackets editor, and reload.

Comment: This decision is for global settings. But question is about project specific settings. They are not working for me as well